# Capturing MSN Chat via Memory

Tags: c++, chat, capture, msn

Is it possible, or does anyone know the best way to capture MSN chats?  I was thinking about attaching to the MSN process, and messing about searching for static addresses for conversations, to capture them.

(This is all on the windows platform using c++)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would probably be easiest to sniff packets on the ports known to be used by MSN.  That has the added benefit of working with clients other than the Microsoft one (such as Pidgin).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the protocol is unencrypted, it would probably be easier to attach to the process and intercept the network traffic than to search all of the application memory for chats.  But that's no small task, either.

Comment: Wouldn't just attaching to the network interfaces (like WireShark does) be easier in this case?

Answer (score 0):

omg i just googled and discovered there's a whole cottage industry around doing this. pay $60+ to record MSN chat - are you kidding ? .. Please~ someone release an Open Source solution.